# Django: How to pass validation of uniquely constrained field in order to update model record

Tags: python, django

I've created a view that pre-loads information from a previous entry and allows the user to make and save changes.

I have a unique constraint in my model for a particular field which I need to maintain for initial record creation. However if they submit the form in the edit view with the same entry value for this field it obviously doesn't validate.

I see there being some scenarios:

1. **Initial unique field value == edited unique field value**:

   Doesn't pass validation but I want it to update the record.
2. **Initial unique field value != edited unique field value**:

   Validates if field value not in fields list then Creates new record or 
   doesn't validate as field value is in field list and returns unique errors to template

I need to provide a means to pass validation in '1.' to enable me to update the record. Should I override the Validate method for the field or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks